# Parsley Form Validation - Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, parsley.js

Ok, so i have searched everywhere for this but still can't get it working. No one seems to have tried it but i'm sure it can do it.

I want to use the Parsley validation plugin with my twitter bootstrap project. I have read the docs, but am still learning JQuery so it's going right over my head (i'm rationalising that it is too advanced for me at the moment).

I want to add a custom event listener to Parsley to show a popup on error instead of the ugly li's. This is what i have tried:

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.parsley').parsley({
        successClass: 'success',
        errorClass: 'error',
        errors: {
            classHandler: function(el) {
                return $(el).closest('.form-control');
            },
            errorsWrapper: '<div class=\"popover fade top in\" style=\"top: -20px\"></div>',
            errorElem: '<div></div>'
        }
    });


    $('.test').parsley({

        successClass: 'success',
        errorClass: 'error',
        errors: {
            classHandler: function(el) {
                return $(el).closest('.form-control');
            },
            errorElem: '<div></div>'
        },

        onFieldValidate: function ( elem ) {

            // if field is not visible, do nothing.
            if ( !$( elem ).is( ':visible' ) ) {
                $(elem).popover({
                    placement : 'top',
                    title : 'Test',
                    content : '<div id="popOverBox"><h4>Test</h4></div>'
                });
                $(elem).popover('show');
                return true;
            } else {
                $(elem).popover('hide');
                return false;
            }
        }

    });

});
```

The top function half works (only displays a bubble) was only a hack to get it working temporarily.

**HTML**

```
<head>

    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/lib/parsley/parsley.min.js"></script>

</head>

<form class="test" data-validate="parsley" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="test" value="test" data-required="true" data-trigger="keyup change">
</form>
```

Can anyone help me get this working?
Note: I would prefer the bootstrap tooltip (as opposed to popover) but would be grateful if someone could help me with either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing what you shouldn't do. Looking at the [Parsley docs](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html#javascript) one can see warning like this:

> you must remove data-validate="parsley" auto-binding code in your
>   forms DOM to allow you to override the default processing and use
>   Parsley purely from javascript.

After that you can do `$('.test').parsley(...)`.

Also note that you are hanging listeners incorrectly. The right way is to put them inside `listenter: {}` property just like this:

```
$('.test').parsley({
    listeners: {
        onFieldValidate: function(elem, ParsleyField) {
            console.log("validate", elem);
            return false;
        },
        onFieldError: function(elem, constraints, ParsleyField) {
            console.log("error", elem);
        }
    }
});
```

Simple example could be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c6St6/)

Comment: Nice one, will give it a go. Cheers!

Comment: I've just seen that big yellow warning! gahh how did i miss that!

Answer (score 1):

You can simple check if your form is validated or not by using following code.

```
$( '#formId' ).parsley( 'isValid' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this in conjunction with bootstrap tooltips, the below snippet adds a title to invalid fields.

`parsleyContainer` = Field container, this could be a `<form>` tag for example

```
var parsleyContainer = $(this).closest('.tab-pane');
$(parsleyContainer).attr('data-parsley-validate', 'true');
$(parsleyContainer).parsley({
    errorsContainer: function (ParsleyField) {
        return ParsleyField.$element.attr("title");
    },
    errorsWrapper: false,
});

if($(parsleyContainer).parsley().validate()) {
    //do something is validated
}
```