# Validate with ParsleyJS and display errors with twitter tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, listener, parsley.js

I would like to validate a form with parsley js and display the errors (if any) with twitter's bootstrap tooltip.

I read this [link](http://victor.stodell.se/2013/12/using-bootstrap-tooltip-to-show-parsley.html) about the twitter bootstrap integration with parsley and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072178/parsley-form-validation-event-listeners) about EventListeners.  However, I am still not able to display the error messages.

**That's how I implemented it**

```
... 
<input id="id_email" name="email" required=True parsley-type="email">
<button type="submit" onclick="javascript:$('#id_email').parsley(parsleyOptions); ">Next</button>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/parsley/parsley.js"%}"></script>
...
    <script>

    // parsley option
    var parsleyOptions = {
      // Sets success and error class to Bootstrap class names
      successClass: 'has-success',
      errorClass: 'has-error',

      // Bootsrap needs success/error class to be set on parent element
      errors: {
        classHandler: function(el) {
          return el.parent();
        },
        // Set these to empty to make sure the default Parsley elements are not rendered
        errorsWrapper: '',
        errorElem: ''
      },
      listeners: {
        // Show a tooltip when a validation error occurs
        onFieldError: function (elem, constraints, parsleyField) {
          elem.tooltip({
            animation: false,
            container: 'body',
            placement: 'top',
            title: elem.data('error-message')
          });
        },
        // Hide validation tooltip if field is validated
        onFieldSuccess: function(elem, constraints, parsleyField) {
          elem.tooltip('destroy');
        }
      }
    };

    </script>
...
```

The tooltip is not triggered with an error in the form field (even with an empty field, no error is raised). How can I get that parsley is triggering the tooltip to work?

Side notes:

- The code about the 'parsleyOptions' is taken from [here](http://victor.stodell.se/2013/12/using-bootstrap-tooltip-to-show-parsley.html)
- all js files are accessable
- a static tooltip over an input field works
- parsley js works when the error is displayed in a div

Comment: I don't have twitter tooltip set up to check your code, but can you add a `console.log` before the `elem.tooltip` to ensure that the listener is being executed?

Comment: The listener doesn't seem to be triggered. No print out from console.log

Comment: From what I can debug, the `parsleyOptions` are not loaded. If I execute `parsley('validate')`, the error message is displayed.

Comment: I just looked a bit more at your code: why do you `onclick="javascript:$('#id_email').parsley(parsleyOptions);"` like that? You shouldn't invoke parsley on the button click, you set it running when the page loads.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are interested in a way to accomplish this using parsley 2.x:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    <input id="id_email" name="email" class="required" data-parsley-type="email">
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        // instanciate parsley and set the container 
        // as the element title without a wrapper
        $("#myForm").parsley({
            errorsContainer: function (ParsleyField) {
                return ParsleyField.$element.attr("title");
            },
            errorsWrapper: false
        });

        // when there is an error, display the tooltip with the error message
        $.listen('parsley:field:error', function(fieldInstance) {
            var messages = ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(fieldInstance);
            fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('destroy');
            fieldInstance.$element.tooltip({
                animation: false,
                container: 'body',
                placement: 'top',
                title: messages
            });
        });

        // destroy tooltip when field is valid
        $.listen('parsley:field:success', function(fieldInstance) {     
            fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('destroy');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0 and Parsley.js 2.0.2. I've created a fiddle with this: http://jsfiddle.net/C96ab/3/

Comment: Great answer! I've modified your solution by adding action to success event, so tooltip is removed when field is validated.
`$.listen('parsley:field:success', function(fieldInstance) {
    fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('destroy');
});`

Comment: For __Bootstrap 4.x__, replace `tooltip('destroy')` with `tooltip('dispose')`. For __Bootstrap 5.x__, replace `tooltip('destroy')` with `tooltip.dispose()`